# How to get variables to behave like arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

```
private static int test[] =new int[]{2};

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(test[0]);
    test(test);
    System.out.println(test[0]);
}
private static void test(int[] test3) {
    test3[0]=test3[0]+12;
}
```

Printed :

```
2
14
```

How can I achieve this without using arrays? If I use

```
private static int test = 2
```

or

```
private static Integer test = 2
```

it's stays 2

Comment: Use a custom class that holds an int field and change the value held by the field. In other words this will only work with non-immutable reference types, not with primitives.

Comment: Or return a value from the method and reassign the returned value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to change the method to not make side effects like that. Something like

```
private static int addTwelve(int value) {
    return value + 12;
}
```

and then assign the value when the method returns

```
test = addTwelve(test); //or just 'test += 12;' in this case
```

Since java use pass-by-value semantics, you pass the value of the integer to the method and not the variable (or reference to the variable). When you change the variable in the method it is *only* changed in the method. The reason it works with the array is that an array is an object and when calling a method with an object as parameter the reference to the object is copied.

That also means you can create a class that have the value as a property and call the `test` method with an instance of the class. It could look like this

```
public class TestClass {
    private int test = 2;
    //more if you need to.

    public void setTest(int value) {
        this.test = value;
    }
    public int getTest() {
        return this.test;
    }
}
```

And the method:

```
private static void test(TestClass x) {
     x.setTest(x.getTest() + 12); 
}
```

An `addTwelve` method could be created in the `TestClass` or even better (depending on the use case ofcourse) an `addValue(int value)` in the class.

Comment: OK Thank you very much but what is more efficient to use the array with only one value or to create the class ? (less cpu power)

Comment: @user2387586 Not a difference you will ever notice. Always try to write readable code, before you try to make it more efficient. If performance ever becomes a problem you can try to improve the code and even in that case I can almost guarantee that this choice will make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your assignment on the variable itself:

```
private static int test = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(test);
    test = test(test);
    System.out.println(test);
}
private static int test(int test) { 
    return test+12;
}
```

Or, without the method invocation:

```
private static int test = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(test);
    test += 12 // this is the same as: test = test+12
    System.out.println(test);
}
```